# How to validate a Chinese phone number with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Please I am trying to validate a Chinese phone number, which has the condition of having to start with 1 followed by 10 other number for eg.

14375847232

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it! thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
/^1[0-9]{10}$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` Beginning of a string
- `1` Matches 1 character
- `[0-9]` Matches 0-9 characters
- `{10}` Matches 10 of the preceding token (0-9)
- `$` End of a string

Comment: just tried it in regexr and doesn't seem to work

Comment: Works here: https://regex101.com/r/eeOBen/1

Comment: Works here too: https://regexr.com/56s30

Comment: Yep just rechecked, I think I copied it wrong